# Angular2 / Webpack : how to load correctly a compressed bundle.js file?

Tags: angular, webpack

I used the Webpack Compression plugin to compress my bundle.js
I actually got a bundle.js.gz

However when running the app, I get an error message :

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://example.com/js/app/bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Checking the request/repons headers , I can see that request headers are ok

```
Request headers
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, b
```

And the more-type in the response is effectively text/html and not application/javascript

```
Response headers
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, b
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
```

How can I load the correct bundle.js ?

**update**

when both versions bundle.js and bundle.js.gz are present in my public/js/app directory , then it runs fine... and surprising me this is the bundle.js.gz which is served !

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 platon platon 339K Dec  8 14:14 bundle.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 platon platon  **89K** Dec  8 14:14 **bundle.js.gz**
```

in the chrome dev tool :

Name.     Status Type.   Initiator.  **Size.**   Time
   bundle.js    200 script  (index):15  **89.6 KB** 1.52 s

I guess it's the standard way ...
why 2 both versions should be present ?  thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0):

the webpack compression plugin is not useful.
once minified with the UglifyJsPlugin and the webpack command option --optimize-minimize, the compress/uncompress process is performed by Nginx

```
##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gunzip on;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript $
```